# Which software can I install on rasppberry pi to write image files on to sd cards?

Tags: sd-card

I did'nt get any errors using  sudo dd bs=4M if=raspian.img of=/dev/sda1, the terminal showed success but when I plug my sd card into the pi, pi was not booting up!
Can someone suggest me some softwares which I can install on raspberry pi to write images onto to other sd-cards.

Comment: Welcome. There is nothing wrong with `dd` -- you are using it incorrectly.  You don't have to bother reading the duplicate question, just read the accepted answer.   You should be using `/dev/sda`, not `/dev/sda1`.  The first is the whole card.  The second is just the first partition, which will not produce a workable result.

Comment: I tried both I think, I'm not sure!

Comment: Well, there's nothing subjective or ambiguous here, presuming `/dev/sda` is the card; `/dev/sda1` *cannot* be the card, it can only be a filesystem partition.   If `dd if=raspbian.img of=/dev/sda bs=4M` doesn't work, there's no point in trying anything else because the only explanation for that would be: 1) Defective hardware/card, 2) A corrupted or invalid image file.

Comment: dd worked with /dev/sda